# How to use linq to sql to return a partial string of text

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I wrote this SQL server select statement to only return 204 characters and append ... to the end if there was more than 204 chars in that row.

```
SELECT Name, Active, Image, CASE WHEN LEN(Description) <= 204 THEN Description ELSE LEFT (Description , 204) + '...' END AS 'Short Description' FROM Brands
```

How do I finish this linq code to do the same?

```
var query = db.Brands.Select(p=> new{
        Brand =p,
        p.Description.Length <-- I believe this is a starting point?>
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the literal translation would be:

```
var query = db.Brands.Select(p => new {
        Brand = p,
        Description = p.Description.Length < 204 
                          ? p.Description 
                          : p.Description.Substring(0, 204) + "..."
    });
```

But I'd be surprised if that worked...

Is it absolutely crucial that you do this on the SQL side, rather than at the client? For example, this *will* work:

```
var query = db.Brands
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(p => new {
        Brand = p,
        Description = p.Description.Length < 204 
                          ? p.Description 
                          : p.Description.Substring(0, 204) + "..."
    });
```

Comment: Is that the best way to do that? I included the SQL code just for an example of what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: It says invalid anonymous type member declarator.

Comment: I don't think this will compile... you need to specify the property name explicitly (`Description = ...`) because the compiler can't infer it in that case

Comment: @Thomas, I believe you are correct, but I still am having trouble with the syntax.

Comment: Checked with Entity Framework (.Net 4.0) - it could translate it to SQL query. Finally it contained this in query CASE WHEN (( CAST(LEN([Extent1].[Text]) AS int)) > 10) THEN SUBSTRING([Extent1].[Text], 0 + 1, 10) ELSE [Extent1].[Text] END AS [C2]

Comment: @The_Smallest: Wow, I'm impressed :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, what is the .AsEnumerable for? It works with and without it.

Comment: @nick: If the SQL translation didn't work, it would basically pull down the Brand object directly, and perform the rest of the query (the projection) in .NET itself instead.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write it is as follows:

```
var query = db.Brands.Select(p=> new{
        Brand =p,
        c= p.Description.Length < 204 ? p.Description 
                               : p.Description.Substring(0, 204) + "..."
    });
```